# Trying to display buttons based on PHP if statement echo's, but multiple buttons are being displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a feature, on my social networking site, which allows users to `favourite` another user (essentially add them as a friend). I am displaying all the favourites of the logged in users in  a div on the right hand side of my page.

How the logged in user can `favourite` or `un-favourite` someone.

1. User can go  onto anyones profile page where these buttons will be displayed (full code will be displayed below):

   ```
   echo "<form method='post'>
           <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
           <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
         </form>";
   ```
2. Lets assume I am logged in as `Conor` and I click the `Add to Favourites` button. This will execute an `INSERT` query which will send data to my `favourites` table in my database about who favourited the user, and which user is favourited.
3. The idea is that once a user is already favourited by the logged in user, it will display a different set of buttons, i.e., `Add to Favourites` will be replaced by `Remove from Favourites`:

**The problem:**
Let's assume I am logged in as Conor, and Conor has `favourited` Alice and Freddy. What I expect to see is when I go onto both there profile pages, both Alice and Freddy should have the `Remove from Favourites` button displayed on their profiles, yet only Alice has the `Remove from Favourites` button displayed (maybe because she was the first person favourited by the logged in user?). I assume that because my `mysqli_fetch_array()` was not in a `while` loop, that this may be the issue, that it isn't checking it for every user in the logged in users favourites. But upon implementing the while loop, it just displays several `add to favourites` buttons.

I am also trying to specify (an extra check) that if the logged in user ($username) has already favourited the profile of the person they are checking (`$user`), then do not execute the `INSERT query`.

**Here is the full code regarding this issue**:

```
  $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user
    // Get all the favourites of the logged in user...
    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE favourited_by='$username'");
    $num_of_favs = mysqli_num_rows($q);
    while ($r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];
// Three conditions needed:
// 1. Con 1: Dont display any buttons for the logged in user as they cannot fav or msg themselves.
// 2. Con 2: Display sendmsg and addfriend btn if the user is not in the logged in users favs
// 3. Con 3: Display sendmsg and remfriend btn is the user is in the logged in users favs.

// Condition 1:
if ($user == $username){
      // dont display buttons     
} 
// Condition 2:
if ($user != $username && $favourited_who != $db_fav_who){ // if $user is not equal to db fav_who value
    echo "<form method='post'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
              </form>";
    }     
// Condition 3:
if ($user != $username && $favourited_who == $db_fav_who) { 
        echo "<form method='post'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-warning' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
              </form>";
        }
    }

/******************************************/
/* code to process a favourite request*/

if (isset($_POST['addfriend'])) { 
    $fav_request    = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user

    // Get all the favourites of the logged in user...
    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE favourited_by='$username'");
    $num_of_favs = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        $r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];

    if ($user != $username) { // Check: See user isnt favouriting themself.
        if ($db_fav_who == $user && $db_fav_by == $username){
            // do nothing if the user is already favourited
        } else {
        $favourite_user = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO favourites VALUES ('', '$favourited_who', '$favourited_by')");
        header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }
} // if isset closed

/********************************************/

/* Removing someone from there favourites. */
if (isset($_POST['remfriend'])) { 
    $del_request    = $_POST['remfriend'];
    $rem_q = mysqli_query ($connect, "DELETE FROM favourites WHERE favourited_who = '$favourited_who' AND favourited_by ='$favourited_by' ");
    header("Refresh:0");
}

?>
```

Comment: You are getting list of favourited users, but showing button for one user.You need to check "favourite" status for one user only:  WHERE favourited_by='$username' A ND favourited_who = '$user'

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @TuanDuong - ahh I see! It worked! Many thanks!

Comment: @tadman - Thank you for your input!